# When do we need to register a .Net dll and a COM dll?

Tags: .net

I am not clear about when do we need to register dlls? I guess we register .net dll if it needs to be accessed from a COM dll and we register COM dll if it needs to be accessed from a .net dll. Is this correct? Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance for any clarifications.

Comment: COM dlls always need to be registered to be useable.

Answer (score 3):

A COM dll always needs to be registered.

If the .Net DLL exposes a COM interface then it to needs to be registered.

Comment: I have to register the COM dll on the develop machine to be able to program against it and get intellisence and so on, but on the target machine it seems like it's fine just to have the dll in the same folder as the program to make it work. Is that not true?

Comment: I find registering the COM DLL "Office.dll" isn't necessary for my purposes. Without the DLL however, my .NET 3.5 app on WinXP crashes (though works on Win7). So are you sure it ALWAYS needs to be registered?